# htaccess rewrite rules - domain/subdomain https/www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my main domain and a subdomain. Subdomain is located in a subdirectory on the root directory of main domain and this cannot be changed. Main domain has an SSL while subdomain doesn't.

Now I am trying to force `https` and `www` for the main domain and force no `https` and no `www` for the subdomain. So at the end the main domain disregarding how it will try to be accessed should redirect at `https://www.example.com` and same time subdomain should be `http://sub.example.com`

All other possible combinations of accessing them should redirect to the above 2. So far, I am successfull to do this for the most possibilities but I am failing to do so for the case when I access the subdomain with `https://sub.example.com`. It won't redirect to the http version, rather it will try to load the page through https, browser throws the security warning about the SSL and if I proceed, it load the contents of the main domain site through the subdomain and the insecure warning on the browser.

Following is the htaccess rules I am trying, on the htaccess on the root directory, that affects both main site and subdomain.

How to improve them and achieve the desired outcome?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect only the main domain to https, you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#https to http (subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
 #main domain

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```